# textpos error with newenvironment{aside} and xelatex

Tags: environments, compiling

I'm using xelatex with texlive 2011 vanilla on the latest ubuntu precise pangolin.

I fork and try to use the great cv template from https://github.com/afriggeri/cv
This template uses TikZ for the header, XeTeX and fontspec with Helvetica Neue font (extracted from dfont with `fondu` program).

When i try to compile with `xelatex cv.tex` i have one error like this :

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textpos/textpos.sty
Package: `textpos' 1.7g <2010 September 30>
Grid set 16 x 16 = 38.39343pt x 49.68562pt
TextBlockOrigin set to 0pt x 0pt
)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \aside.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.169 }
```

Which refers to this portion of source code into `friggeri-cv.cls`

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#1` there is the first argument of `\aside` but it is declared with no arguments, hence the error. If you make a nested definition and want to refer to the first parameter of the inner macro use `##1`.